# PWA - Launch directly into WebXR

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, oculus, webxr

I understand that user interaction is required to launch immersive VR/AR applications on the web, but it seems like allowing direct launching is an important feature for 3D only WebXR PWAs.

i.e Once a PWA is downloaded, allow app to launch directly into immersive vr. My use case is for B2B applications in kiosk mode, where staff can power on several devices and have them go straight into the experience without putting on the headset.

Is this possible or planned for Chrome Android and/or Oculus Browser?

I was hoping that adding `"display":"fullscreen"` to the `app.webmanifest` would allow this, but it looks like that just addresses how the window is drawn.

Answer (score 3):

With some help from the folks on the [WebXR Discord](https://discord.com/invite/webxr), I have learned that this functionality is covered in the WebXR spec, listed [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/webxr/#application-launch).

[image]

It doesn't seem to be implemented in any browsers at this point, although the Oculus team has indicated that it is on their radar.